# Issue with max-line-length with pylint

Tags: vim, pylint, pylintrc

I've got this setting in my `.pylintrc`

```
# Maximum number of characters on a single line. 
max-line-length=78
```

But error about line greater than 78 chars in vim is not reporting. Pylint is however working as it reports other errors like "trailing spaces".

What's wrong with my setup?

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug  2 2017 00:45:39)
Rustines incluses : 1-160
Modifié par <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compilé par <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Énorme version sans interface graphique.
  Fonctionnalités incluses (+) ou non (-) :
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
         fichier vimrc système : "/etc/vimrc"
     fichier vimrc utilisateur : "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2me fichier vimrc utilisateur : "~/.vim/vimrc"
      fichier exrc utilisateur : "$HOME/.exrc"
               $VIM par défaut : "/etc"
        $VIMRUNTIME par défaut : "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation : gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Édition de liens : gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -Wl,-z,relro  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lnsl  -lselinux  -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -fstack-protector  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
```

---

```
$ pylint --version
pylint 1.6.5, 
astroid 1.4.9
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

All help welcome !

Comment: What vim plugin do you use to run pylint? Syntastic? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118565/how-can-i-set-the-python-max-allowed-line-length-to-120-in-syntastic-for-vim help?

Comment: I’m using Syntastic

Answer (score 0):

Well, I end up by upgrading VIM from 7.4 to 8.0 and nows it works...